# JRE 7.0_71-b14 crashes :- SIGSEGV problematic frame HandleMarkCleaner::~HandlerMarkCleaner()

Tags: java, linux, jvm, ibm-mq

We are observing JVM crashes when JVM is under load. It crashes with

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr= 0x0000000000000000

It always fails at HandleMarkCleaner::~HandlerMarkCleaner() when Object.notify() method was being executed.

```
Stack: [0x00007fc178052000,0x00007fc178153000],  sp=0x00007fc178151560,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x34a10f]  HandleMarkCleaner::~HandleMarkCleaner()+0x1f
V  [libjvm.so+0x58f3ce]  JVM_MonitorNotify+0xba
J  java.lang.Object.notify()V

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  java.lang.Object.notify()V
J  com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalHconn.leaveCall()V
j  com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$4.run()V+230
J  com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiWorkerThread.run()V
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

> Environment

- Java Vm: Java HotSpot (TM) 64 bit Server VM (24.71-b01 mixed mode
  linux-amd64 compressed oops)
- OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4

Looking at OpenJDK HandleMarkCleaner source code

```
class HandleMarkCleaner: public StackObj {
 private:
  Thread* _thread;
 public:
  HandleMarkCleaner(Thread* thread) {
    _thread = thread;
    _thread->last_handle_mark()->push();
  }
  ~HandleMarkCleaner() {
    _thread->last_handle_mark()->pop_and_restore();
  }

 private:
  inline void* operator new(size_t size, void* ptr) {
    return ptr;
  }
};
```

it appears, somehow

> _thread

pointer in HandleMarkCleaner object is getting invalid. Has anyone  encountered such JVM crashes? If you know how to resolve this issue please suggest.

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Comment: I'd suggest opening a support ticket with your JVM vendor (you didn't mention which JVM you're using). SIGSEGV is always a bug.

Comment: You might try reproducing without compressed oops.

Comment: hi Nicholas, I tried -XX:-UseCompressedOops however JVM still crashed at destructor of HandlerMarkCleaner. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Upgrade to a newer JVM (and why are you using a beta build?), browse your JVM vendor's bug database (looks like this is OpenJDK based) and open a support ticket if there isn't one already.